# While trying to open jmeter through .bat it displays error

Tags: jmeter

I am Krishna Moorthy. I was trying to download and install jmeter in my 64 bit laptop with windows 10. It got downloaded and I have extracted the file.

Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAqo0.png)
errorlevel=2
Press any key to continue . . .

I tried with the setting the path, copying "findstr" from windows32 from C.
But it still shows the same. Path in the environment variable is also properly setenter link description here

I am not able to understand this. do i need to uninstall and try it again? Already I have done it once.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, it's more recommended to ask software-related questions on [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

As per [Apache JMeter main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> The Apache JMeter™ application is open source software, a **100% pure Java application** designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance.

It means that you need a [Java Runtime Environment](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) in order to be able to run JMeter so make sure to download a 64-bit version of JRE for Windows version 8 or higher and once done you should be able to launch JMeter.

More information and detailed steps just in case: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans)